# PHP, PDO, mySQL Issue with lastInsertId()

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I have a MVC framework that I'm using. I'm trying to insert a customer to the DB and return its ID at the same time.

I've reviewed the posts below and tried what they say but I still can't seem to get it to work properly. The best I've been able to get is having the last `lastInsertId()` to return `null`.

[lastInsertId() returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47954276/16096837)

[PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10680943/16096837)

[SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917695/16096837)

This is part of my Database.php library so you understand what I'm doing in the model (The last function is where I call the `lastInsertId()`):

```
<?php
    class Database {
        private $dbHost = DB_HOST;
        private $dbUser = DB_USER;
        private $dbPass = DB_PASS;
        private $dbName = DB_NAME;

        private $statement;
        private $dbHandler;
        private $error;

        public function __construct() {
            $conn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->dbHost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            try {
                $this->dbHandler = new PDO($conn, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $options);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $this->error;
            }
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }

        //Allows us to write queries
        public function query($sql) {
            $this->statement = $this->dbHandler->prepare($sql);
        }

        //Bind values
        public function bind($parameter, $value, $type = null) {
            switch (is_null($type)) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
            $this->statement->bindValue($parameter, $value, $type);
        }

        //Execute the prepared statement
        public function execute() {
            return $this->statement->execute();
        }

        //Execute and return last ID
        public function exAndReturn() {
            $this->statement->execute();
            return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        }
```

And here is the model where I query the DB and attempt to return the ID.

```
public function createAndReturnCustomer($data) {

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO customer(first_name, last_name, phone_number_1, phone_number_2, phone_opt_out, email_1, email_2, email_opt_out, referral_type_id, referral_detail, company_name, company_as_customer, re_agent, created_date
    ) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number_1, :phone_number_2, :phone_opt_out, :email_1, :email_2, :email_opt_out, :referral_type_id, :referral_detail, :company_name, :company_as_customer, :re_agent, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )');
    
    $this->db->bind(':first_name', $data->first_name);
    $this->db->bind(':last_name', $data->last_name);
    $this->db->bind(':phone_number_1', $data->phone_number_1);
    $this->db->bind(':phone_number_2', $data->phone_number_2);
    $this->db->bind(':phone_opt_out', $data->phone_opt_out);
    $this->db->bind(':email_1', $data->email_1);
    $this->db->bind(':email_2', $data->email_2);
    $this->db->bind(':email_opt_out', $data->email_opt_out);
    $this->db->bind(':referral_type_id', $data->referral_type);
    $this->db->bind(':referral_detail', $data->referral_detail);
    $this->db->bind(':company_name', $data->company_name);
    $this->db->bind(':company_as_customer', $data->company_as_customer);
    $this->db->bind(':re_agent', $data->re_agent);

    return $this->db->exAndReturn();

}
```

As of right now it's returning:

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lastInsertId()
> on string in ...

I understand that I can write another function to force retrieve the last inserted entry in the DB, but I wanted to do this correctly to avoid any future issues that may happen with expansion and multiple users potentially performing the same actions simultaneously.

Comment: `$this->conn` is a reference to your connection string. I'm assuming it should be `$this->dbHandler`

Comment: @ChrisHaas You are a genius. I absolutely love you. Thanks my man. I changed it to ```$this->dbHandler``` and it works fine now.

Comment: Also, minor critique, and maybe your code is handling this elsewhere, but make sure you surface whether the database connection actually failed in the constructor somehow.

Comment: _Side note:_ I don't really see the point of wrapping your PDO connection in a "Database" class when all you're doing is more or less replicating PDO's methods (and confusingly so, since `query()` is very different from `prepare()`). It's also a very bad idea to echo the connection error since all that will do is confuse some and give others unnecessary info (like db-host, username etc). There's also no real reason to catch the PDO exception at all since the app rarely can continue if the database connection fails. Let your applications main error handler handle it